# Referencing data from ASP.NET MVC controller in Javascript file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am currently working on a project that implements ComponentOne studio's Wijmo frameworks and I have built a grid that uses data passed from a Model that basically builds some dummy data for an individual sale.

I am then calling the public static IEnumerable in my Controller file which is passing a value for the number of data entries to create. That is being passed to my view for my Index cshtml file, where the data grid is being built.

I am trying to then figure out how to call the data that has been created when I am writing a function in a JS file. I want to be able to take the collective data that was produced by the int value in my controller (say 100 entries) and then create a view of that data that I am filtering on. However, I can't figure out how to pass that initial data so that when I run the filter on it I can reference that data to save a view of the output and run a secondary filter.

I basically need to figure out how the reference in the JS calls not just the model, but the model with the int value from the controller.

Here is the model file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace FilterPanel.Models
{
    public class Sale
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    private static List<string> COUNTRIES = new List<string> { "US", "UK", "Canada", "Japan", "China", "France", "German", "Italy", "Korea", "Australia" };
    private static List<string> PRODUCTS = new List<string> { "Widget", "Gadget", "Doohickey" };

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="total"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<Sale> GetData(int total)
    {
        var rand = new Random(0);
        var dt = DateTime.Now;
        var list = Enumerable.Range(0, total).Select(i =>
        {
            var country = COUNTRIES[rand.Next(0, COUNTRIES.Count - 1)];
            var product = PRODUCTS[rand.Next(0, PRODUCTS.Count - 1)];
            var startDate = new DateTime(dt.Year, i % 12 + 1, 25);

            return new Sale
            {
                ID = i + 1,
                Start = startDate,
                Country = country,
                Product = product,
                Active = (i % 4 == 0)
            };
        });
        return list;
    }
}
```

}

I am then referencing this function in the controller file:

```
using FilterPanel.Models;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace FilterPanel.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(Sale.GetData(100).ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

And finally trying to call that data in my JS file with "data" being a placeholder for the Sale.GetData(100) that I am trying to pass

```
var view = new wijmo.collections.CollectionView(data);

  // create a second CollectionView based on the first one
  var view2 = new wijmo.collections.CollectionView(view.items, {
        collectionChanged: function(s) {
        var cnt = document.getElementById('cnt');
      cnt.textContent = wijmo.format('{length:n0}', s.items)
  }
});
```

Comment: Please see [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to include the *shortest code possible to reproduce your problem*

Comment: Razor pages and modern JavaScript don't work together very well. The way to do what you want is to generate a `<script>var __MyData = @JSON.Encode(Model.Data);</script>` in your view and then you can use that variable in your JavaScript.